# Relative Motion of Three Particle System

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Here is the question.

> Particle A moves North with a constant speed of $V$ and Particle B moves South with the same constant speed of $V$. Another particle C moves to the South-east with respect to particle A and and the same particle C moves making an angle of $30$ degrees with North, with respect to particle B. What is the velocity of particle C?

I have written two relative velocity equations for both A and B.

$\vec V_{C|A}=\vec V_{C}-\vec V_{A}$

$\vec V_{C|B}=\vec V_{C}-\vec V_{B}$

I can't seem to figure out what to do next. There seems to be three unknowns whereas I only have two equations. How should I solve this ?

Comment: @Semiclassical I edited the question. Thanks for pointing out the error in it.

Comment: Good start. What I'd suggest at this point is to write out the velocities in coordinate form with unknown components for $\vec{V}_C$. That'll depend a bit on your notation: Intro physics books often use $\hat{i},\hat{j}$ whereas math books often use $e_x,e_y$. But once you've done this, try using these expressions to write the relative velocities and draw conclusions about their components.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Vector $\vec V_C$ is the median of a triangle with base $2V$ and base angles of $30°$ and $45°$ (see figure). With a little trig you can then compute:
$$
V_C=\sqrt{11-6\sqrt3}\ V.
$$

[image]